# Defining the terms "old interest" and "new interest" (across a variety of disciplines)

Tags: economics, interest, macro-economics

This is a bit of a vocabulary / concept tackle (these two, tackling each other).

My question is about this.

How would a financial analyst define and extrapolate and make the reader (or, user) envision, what discrepancies and differences are in the financial terms

"Old interest"

and

"New interest"

(if, allowed

let me say

(as also used in economics).

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to cite some examples of such usage.